# complex numbers quadratic equation question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

how to solve $z^2 +3|z| = 0   , z$ complex ? treating the complex number as $a+bi $ or anything similar didnt help much...also solving like simple algebric equations also didnt prove effective and didnt solve this the right way. are there other methods to solution?

Comment: explain votes to close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $z=re^{it}$, you have 
$$r^2e^{2it}+3r=0$$
$$r(re^{2it}+3)=0\ .$$
Hence $r=0$. i.e. z=0, and $re^{2it}=-3$, i.e r=3 and $e^{2it}=-1$, i.e. $e^{it}=\pm i$.

The three solutions are thus $z=0$ and $z=\pm 3i$.

Comment: The ans is correct, but $z(z+3i)(z-3i)=z^2+3|z|$ ? :p

Comment: Why should it be?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.

$$z^2=-3|z|,$$ 
taking the norm gives

$$|z|^2=3|z|$$
so  $|z|=3$ or $|z|=0$

If $|z|=3$ we have $z^2=-9$ and $z=\pm 3i$
so the solutions are $z=0, \pm 3i$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$z^2=-3|z|$ which is real  $\implies z$ is either purely imaginary or purely real as demonstrated below

$z=a+ib\implies a^2-b^2+2abi+2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=0$

Equating the imaginary parts, $ab=0$

Comment: so either a is 0, b is zero, or both are zero?

Comment: @Bak1139, Check for all the three cases

Answer (score 0):

If we use exponential  representation  $z=\rho e^{i \theta}$ then  $$\rho^2 e^{2i \theta}+3\rho=0 \Rightarrow \rho=0 \;\;\text{or}\;\; \rho e^{2i\theta}+3=0 \\
\rho e^{2i\theta}+3=0 \Leftrightarrow \rho=-3e^{-2i\theta} \Leftrightarrow -2\theta =\pi(2n+1) \;\;\text{and}\;\;\rho=3$$